# Spring boot hold an application for a domain

Tags: spring

I'm on my VPS server applications written using Spring Boot. It works by default on port 8080. I have access to it via IP address eg. IP: 8080. I wonder how I can hook applications in the domain. So the server was available eg. with nameofdomain.com. I know that first I need to hook into my VPS domain name but do not know how to set up Sping.

Edit:

I know how to host my domain VPS. But I do not know how to make the portal accessible directly from the address without specifying the port number 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a **[domain name registrator service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar)**. A well-known example is [GoDaddy](https://uk.godaddy.com), but there must be countless other companies from your country if you would prefer those. The DNS entry recorded by these companies for a small yearly fee will help any future visitors of your application finding your app without having to type an IP address.

*Note: This question has no relation to Spring Boot, the framework you have used has no specific requirement in this case.*

Comment: I know how to host your domain VPS. But I do not know how to make the portal accessible directly from the address without specifying the port number 8080.